# Increasing boldness of "+" with CSS

Tags: css

How do I make the plus sign more bold? Bolding the "+" makes little to no difference compared to the text.

```
#plus_bold, #text_bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qe2em/

Comment: How is this even remotely related to Java or regex?

Comment: Yes, but not bold enough. I want to make the "+" thicker than it already is.

Comment: Use a different font then.

Comment: Try using a different font, or you could do something hacky like `text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;`

Comment: In CSS spec, `bolder` is more bold than `bold` (what am I saying?!). `font-weight: 900` is the maximum, but seems it looks the same. Suggest to use another font. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: @Shivan Raptor: Indeed, what are you saying? Where does it say that `bolder` is more bold than `bold`?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I just changed it to a different font.

Comment: I misread something: *One font weight darker than the parent element* But in this case, the elements are in parallel. Therefore, use `900` is the boldest .

Comment: @GeorgeNewton can you post your final solution as an answer and mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try "heavy Greek cross", http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/271a/index.htm

Or plus sign from FontAwesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/plus/

Later one is more correct if you use it as an icon.

Comment: That would change the identity of the character, breaking e.g. search functionality.

Comment: To maître Korpela: yes, it will change identity, but if it is being used as an icon then there will be no semantic meaning anyway.

Comment: Icons have meanings. But if this is about using a symbol that looks like a plus sign, rather than “+”, then a) this should have been expressed in the question, b) to get the boldness you want, the safest way is to use a simple image.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to change the font-family

```
#plus_bold, #text_bold{
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

here is how it looks [***JsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/TWvJf/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different font family. The design of glyphs in bold typefaces varies by font family. For example, in Times New Roman, the most common browser default font, the stroke width of bold “+” is almost identical with that of regular “+” (and typically the difference gets lost in rasterization) unless the font size is fairly large, 18pt or more. In Arial, there is a visible difference even in 11pt size.

The choice of fonts should of course be made after careful consideration of many aspects, and the boldness of a bold “+” is probably among the lesser details.

Answer (score -1):

You can do `font-weight:900;` which is bolder than bold (700).  900 is the maximum; besides that, you'd have to actually change the font size.

Comment: The largest `font-weight` value is `900`. And setting it does not help unless there is an actual typeface with weight larger than `bold`.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela on the maximum, duly noted--I have changed the answer.  But as far as typefaces go...there are many that support it; I think this is still a valid answer as it should be tested on whatever typeface is being used.  Question asker did not specify what the font was.

Comment: There is no widely available font that has a weight larger than 700.